# I have written a macro for excel which is used for a simulation in Aspen. The macro is working well, except one part which is not working as it should

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro for excel which is used for a simulation in Aspen. The macro is working well, except one part which is not working as it should. I don't now why but the part

```
For j = 0 To 1 
Call Run
Next j
```

in the `Sub Start()` is not executed properly. As the for loop shows the `Call Run` should be executed two times. Sincerly this is not the case. When i run the Sub Start() it works, but the `Call Run` is only executed one time. Here the complete code of the macro in VB. I would be thankful about any advise.

```
Option Explicit
Dim na As Integer
Dim nb As Integer
Dim nc As Integer
'Dim nd As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
'Dim B As Integer
'Dim B As Double
Dim nresults As Integer
Dim Index1 As Integer
Dim Resultfile As String
Dim Resultfolder As String
Dim nlaeufe As Integer
Dim NewBook As Object
Dim ACMObj As Object
Dim nDaten As Integer


Sub Start()
  Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
   nlaeufe = Sheet0.Cells(2, 2)
   Call Clear_Data
  For i = 0 To nlaeufe
   'Sheet0.Cells(3, 2) = nlaeufe - i
    Set ACMObj = GetObject(Sheet0.Cells(1, 2))
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ACMObj.Application.Visible = True
  Call Count_Daten
  Call Add_Daten(ACMObj, nDaten)
  For j = 0 To 2
  Call Run
  Next j
  Call Get_Data
      If ACMObj.Application.Simulation.State <> "Running" Then
  Call Results_newfile
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If
   Next i
End Sub


Sub Get_Data()
 ' If Sheet0.Cells(Index1 - 1, 2).Value <> ACMObj.Application.Simulation.Time Then
    'Sheet0.Cells(Index1, 2).Value = ACMObj.Application.Simulation.Time
    Dim nd
    For nd = 0 To 152
        Sheet0.Cells(32 + nd, 4 + i).Value = ACMObj.Flowsheet.Resolve(Sheet0.Cells(32 + nd, 2)).Value
        Sheet0.Cells(187 + nd, 4 + i).Value = ACMObj.Flowsheet.Resolve(Sheet0.Cells(187 + nd, 2)).Value
    Next nd
    'Index1 = Index1 + 1
    'If RunStatus = 1 Then _
     '   Application.OnTime Now + Sheet0.Cells(4, 2).Value, "Get_Data"
  'Else
  'End If
End Sub


Sub Count_Daten()
  Dim na
  While Sheet0.Cells(6 + na, 4) <> ""
    na = na + 1
  Wend
  nDaten = na - 1
End Sub
Sub Add_Daten(ACMObj, nDaten)
    Dim nb
    Dim B
  For nb = 1 To nDaten
     Set B = ACMObj.Application.Simulation.Flowsheet.Resolve(CStr(Sheet0.Cells(6 + nb, 3)))
     B.Value = Sheet0.Cells(6 + nb, 4 + i).Value
  Next nb
End Sub


Sub Run()
  Set ACMObj = GetObject(Sheet0.Cells(1, 2))
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ACMObj.Application.Visible = True
  ACMObj.Application.Simulation.runmode = "Steady State"
  On Error Resume Next ' In case we are already running
  ACMObj.Run (False)
End Sub


Sub Results_newfile()
  Resultfolder = Sheet0.Cells(1, 8)
  Resultfile = Sheet0.Cells(2, 8)
   ' Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    'NewBook.SaveAs (Resultfolder & Resultfile & ".xls")
    'NewBook.Activate
    'ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheet0.Select
    Range("A1:BA65536").Select
    Selection.Copy
   ' NewBook.Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Call Copy_figure
    'NewBook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub


Sub Clear_Data()
Dim i As Integer
Dim nc As Integer
'i = 100
  Sheet0.Select
  Range("C32:HH166").Select
  Selection.Clear
  While Sheet0.Cells(32 + nc, 3) <> ""
  'Range(Cells(32 + i, 2), Cells(182 + i, 53)).Select
  nc = nc + 152
  Selection.Clear
  i = i + 152
  Wend
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code says FOR J=0 TO 2 ... not 1. That executes RUN 3 times in a row.

Comment: Did you insert a dbg message in sub Run()? What shows up?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know what a dbg message is. And well it doesn't run 3 times. It just runs one time.

Comment: where does Sheet0 come from?  I do not see any declaration and that is not a declared object in excel.  Sheet1 is however.....

Comment: How do you know Run is not running multiple times? Insert this code after `Call Run`: `msgbox "Call Run" & CStr(j)` This will pop up a messagebox every time Call Run is called, and I bet it appears three times. The issue will be somewhere inside the Run procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have displayalerts and an "on error resume next" statement, neither of which are 'turned off' afterwards.

If you temporarily disable these does it give you any error messages or other indication of what might be happening?